# BigQuery LTRIM doesn't return desired result

Tags: google-bigquery

I've got the following SQL code:

```
SELECT LTRIM("0039040123456","0039")
```

The result should be `040123456` but BigQuery returns `40123456`.

Why is the `0` trimmed as well?

Bug or intended behavior?

Many thanks!

Comment: I guess, each character is evaluated for its own? So it trims leading `0`, `3` and `9`?

Comment: What is the source of `0039040123456`?  If from a column, then what is that column's type?

Comment: The column type is `STRING`.

After looking at the docs https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators?hl=de#ltrim I guess this behavior is intended. (Have a look at the fruits example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT LTRIM("0039p40123456","p039")
40123456
```

It removed the `p` too!

That's because:

> If value2 contains more than one character or byte, the function removes all leading or trailing characters or bytes contained in value2.

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators?hl=en#trim

(so it looks at the list of characters, not the sequence of them)

What you really want is:

`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE("0039040123456","^0039","")`

Answer (score 0):

The column type is STRING. After looking at the docs https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators?hl=de#ltrim I guess this behavior is intended. (Have a look at the fruits example.)